# C# with Xamarin Queue.Any () and Queue.Count != 0 does not prevent exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, queue

I am writing a code which reads audio data and send the data to another thread to process fast Fourier transformation. I am using C#'s queue.

Because the queue can be empty, I wrote `if (queue.Count != 0)` to prevent any problems. However, I had an exception saying queue was empty at `queue.Dequeue ()`. I tried `if (queue.Any ())`, but there was no success.

Code:

```
while (recording) {
    if (queue.Any ()) {
        AudioData data = new AudioData (queue.Dequeue ()); // Exception thrown here. It said it was empty.

        // ...
        // Display code.
        // ...
    }
    else
        Thread.Sleep (1);
}
```

Comment: As you are using multiple maybe that's causing the problems try locking the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing from multiple threads, which is a fair assumption as you shouldn't be getting an exception otherwise.. try using the ConcurrentQueue.

More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx